# Product search with SKU in wp e commerce admin panel

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

I want to search product using SKU number in admin panel, and I am using WP E Commerce plugin. I searched many things in google but unable to find exact solution how to change search query, so I can serach any product from it's SKU number.

Can anyone tell me how can I search or in which file I have to make changes and what changes, so that I can get desired result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

WP e-Commerce does not have this functionality at the moment. You can use WooCommerce plugin for your site instead.

While researching I found that WooCommerce executes the following query while searching for a sku = 55

```
SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value LIKE '%55%';
```

But the WP e-Commerce does not. You can add a request in their support forum if you want.